# Limit of sum of bounded iid random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(V^i_N)_{i\ge 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. real random variables such that $|V^i_N|\le c$ for some $c$ independent of $N$. Suppose that each $V^i_N$ converges in law to some random variable $V^i$ with $E[V^i]=m$. Then

$
\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \frac 1N \sum\limits_{i=1}^N V^i_N=m
$
in law.

It seems like it should be solved by the law of large numbers, but they don't have the same mean, so I don't know how to use it here.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: If it's 'in law', then more likely to be CLT

Comment: That's strange, 'in law' means $P(V_n < v) \to_n P(V<v)$, but since $m$ is a constant, what kind of cdf can a constant have?

Comment: Is this an exercise that you're supposed to be proving from scratch, or do you just need a reference to an applicable theorem?

Comment: It is not clear what properties hold for fixed $N$, or for all $i, N$, or what. Nevertheless I believe that repeating the standard proof of the weak law of large numbers (computing the variance of the time average and using Markov/Chebyshev inequality) will be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Setup

For each $N \in \{1, 2 ,3 ,...\}$ let $\{V_N^i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. The variables across different sequences (for different $N$) need not be independent nor identically distributed. Assume there is a finite constant $c$ such that with prob 1:
$$ |V_N^i|\leq c \quad \forall N, i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
Suppose that there are additional random variables $\{V^i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that $E[V^i]=m$ for each $i \in \{1, 2, 3,...\}$ (for some $m \in \mathbb{R}$) and  $V_N^i$ converges in distribution to $V^i$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$. That is, for all points $t \in \mathbb{R}$ at which the CDF of $V^i$ is continuous we have:
$$ \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} P[V_N^i>t] = P[V^i>t]$$

Define
\begin{align}
m_N &= E[V_N^1] \quad \forall N \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}\\
A_N &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N V_N^i\quad \forall N \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}
\end{align}

Observe that $m_N = E[V_N^i]$ for all $i, N \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

#### Claim 1 (Convergence of the means):

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} m_N = m$$

#### Claim 2 (Convergence in probability):

For all $\epsilon>0$ we have $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} P[|A_N-m|\geq \epsilon] = 0$.

#### Proof steps:

- Assume Claim 1 holds.  To prove Claim 2 you can fix $\epsilon>0$, argue that for all sufficiently large $N$ we have $P[|A_N-m|\geq \epsilon] \leq P[|A_N-m_N|\geq \epsilon/2]$, and use the Markov/Chebyshev inequality.
- To prove Claim 1 you can use $V_N^i+c \in [0, 2c]$ with prob 1 and $E[V_N^i+c] = \int_0^{\infty} P[V_N^i+c>t] dt$.

Comment: It is further true that $A_{N^2}\rightarrow m$ with probability 1 as $N\rightarrow\infty$.  It may be the case that $A_N\rightarrow m$ with probability 1 (I'm not sure). Likely there are more general statements for "triangular arrays" as K.A. Buhr has mentioned in another comment.

Comment: Actually, thinking more, it is clear that the 4th moments of all random variables satisfy $$E[(V_N^i - m_N)^4] \leq (2c)^4 \quad \forall N, i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$ and so a more detailed argument shows $A_N\rightarrow m$ with probability 1 (a stronger type of convergence than "convergence in probability").

Answer (score 0):

@Alex:

1) convergence in Law to a certain constant means "Convergence in Probability"

2) if the rv's are iid they HAVE the same mean, same variance and same distribution so the SLLN can be applied and your sequence converges in Law, in Probability and a.s.

3)note that, under some conditions, the SLLN holds also with independent rv's but not identically distributed (Kolmogorov SLLN)

Comment: I believe the idea is that for each fixed $N$, the sequence $(V_N^1,V_N^2,\dots)$ is iid, but $V_N^1$ and $V_{N'}^1$ with $N\neq N'$ are not necessarily independent or identically distributed.

Comment: Also, note that as $N$ increases, the entire sequence changes, so this is a form of the law of large numbers for triangular arrays, not the usual LLN.

Comment: I was confused about the asker's phrase "they don't have the same mean" as well.  I don't know what "convergence in law" means but I think it is the same as "convergence in distribution."